# Openssl synchronization in native JNI C code

Tags: java, c, multithreading, openssl, java-native-interface

I am currently writing a JNI wrapper for a shared C library, which implements some cryptographic functions using the openssl library. The JNI wrapper will be used in a multi-threaded Java application, meaning that the C functions will be called concurrently from multiple Java threads.

Unfortunately the opensssl library is "out of the box" not thread-safe, but the user has to implement and register certain synchronization callback functions which the openssl library will use for synchronization. For more details see [here](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG1).

Now in order to implement those callback functions, I would use for example the `pthread` mutexes on platforms where the POSIX threads are available, but I am not so sure, if it is safe to do so since we are dealing here with the **Java threads** created by the JVM.

How should I proceed? Are there any good examples or documentations which I can learn from?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't know how advanced you are into writing this wrapper, but have you considered using JNA instead? Also, does it have to be native? Doesn't bouncycastle answer your needs already?

Comment: JNA sounds pretty interesting. But I am nearly finished with the wrapper. The JNI C glue code is in my case generated with the SWIG tool, which spares me somewhat from tedious "handwork"... And yes, I have to wrap the native C library, because we don't have resources to reimplement everything in java.

Comment: Java threads are usually built on top of a pthread instance (sometimes referred to as "native" threads).  The Java `Thread` objects will have a corresponding native thread.

Comment: BTW, JNA requires no native code at all, basically allows you to call the native library methods directly from Java (including callbacks for handling locking and synchronization).